# What happens when I save a file using VIM?

Tags: linux, file, vim, filesystems

I used some filesystem changing notify lib to watch the directory `/asdf`, and inside the `asdf`, I `vim tmp`, and made some changes and then use `:wq` to save the file

then I got this output:

```
/asdf/4913 at watch.pl line 9.
/asdf/4913 at watch.pl line 9.
/asdf/tmp at watch.pl line 9.
/asdf/tmp at watch.pl line 9.
/asdf/tmp at watch.pl line 9.
/asdf/tmp~ at watch.pl line 9.
/asdf/tmp~ at watch.pl line 9.
```

what is 4913 file? what is tmp~ file?
what exactly happens after `:wq`  ?

Comment: This site is about programming problems. I dont think that asking about the inner workings of editor X classify as that.

Comment: Try asking this in http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: All self-respecting watchers do something or other to deal with Vim's "weird" writing behavior. If your watcher doesn't you should look for another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3460

> An interesting case was mentioned: Neo/Vim creates a temporary file to check if a directory is writable and see the resulting ACL.
>
> So, if you’re writing software that watches for file changes, you’ll find Vim creates and deletes file 4913 on almost every edit. ref

Additional details
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/sppdpElxY44
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4038/why-does-set-nocompatible-result-in-vim-saving-extra-all-numeric-temporary-fi

Here's the code that's causing this

```
/*
 * Check if we can create a file and set the owner/group to
 * the ones from the original file.
 * First find a file name that doesn't exist yet (use some
 * arbitrary numbers).
 */
STRCPY(IObuff, fname);
for (i = 4913; ; i += 123)
{
    sprintf((char *)gettail(IObuff), "%d", i);
    if (mch_lstat((char *)IObuff, &st) < 0)
        break;
}
fd = mch_open((char *)IObuff,
                O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_EXCL|O_NOFOLLOW, perm);
if (fd < 0)     /* can't write in directory */
    backup_copy = TRUE;
else
{

    ignored = fchown(fd, st_old.st_uid, st_old.st_gid);
    if (mch_stat((char *)IObuff, &st) < 0
        || st.st_uid != st_old.st_uid
        || st.st_gid != st_old.st_gid
        || (long)st.st_mode != perm)
    backup_copy = TRUE;
    /* Close the file before removing it, on MS-Windows we
     * can't delete an open file. */
    close(fd);
    mch_remove(IObuff);
```

Comment: The behavior can be changed with `set backupcopy=X`: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4038/why-does-set-nocompatible-result-in-vim-saving-extra-all-numeric-temporary-fi