# inotify: Watch files changes except for files in .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore, inotify, inotifywait

I'm trying to listen file changes in a folder except .gitignore to trigger rebuild.

It seems like using inotifywait with --exclude option is the right way to do. Does anyone know a good way to convert .gitignore to regex such that inotifywait --exclude can accept correctly?

Comment: Have you heard of continuous integration tools like Jenkins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a full example that watches for changes on non-gitignored files in the current directory, and runs `./build` if any file changes.

One important thing is that `.git/` is not `.gitignored`, so we check and ignore it as well.

```
inotifywait --event close_write --monitor --recursive . |
  while read -r directory events filename; do
    echo "directory events filename: \"${directory}\" \"${events}\" \"${filename}\""
    if ! echo "$directory" | grep -Eq '^\.\/\.git' &&
       ! git check-ignore --non-matching --verbose "${directory}/${filename}" >/dev/null 2>&1
    then
      echo 'will build'
      ./build
    fi
  done
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/blob/adf4c57cdcc4bde958e55939a27f0457730ccd23/run).

If you are a Vim user, you will also want the configs:

```
set backupcopy=no
set noswapfile
set nowritebackup
```

In Vim 8.1, `set backupcopy=no` prevents events of type:

```
directory events filename: "./" "CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE" "4913"
```

The annoying `4913` is mentioned at:

- [What happens when I save a file using VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842835/what-happens-when-i-save-a-file-using-vim)
- https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4038/why-does-set-nocompatible-result-in-vim-saving-extra-all-numeric-temporary-fi

(TODO minimize with `vim -u NONE`) prevents the creation of `.swp` files: [How to prevent vim from creating (and leaving) temporary files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743150/how-to-prevent-vim-from-creating-and-leaving-temporary-files)

Ideally we would also have `--event moved_to,create` but Vim generates 3 events per `:w` in that case, even though I tried to turn off all temporary files (TODO minimize example config with `vim -u NONE`):

```
directory events filename: "./" "MOVED_TO" "README.adoc~"
directory events filename: "./" "CREATE" "README.adoc"
directory events filename: "./" "CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE" "README.adoc"
```

You could also consider to check if the file is git tracked to automatically include the `.git`: [How to tell if a file is git tracked (by shell exit code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405305/how-to-tell-if-a-file-is-git-tracked-by-shell-exit-code) but this approach is better as it uses the new files that you are testing even before they start being tracked.

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to tell inotifywait ahead of time, it's better to run the modified paths through `git check-ignore -nv --stdin`.  Spend more time with the gitignore docs, you'll see why, the patterns come from multiple sources and they're context-sensitive and they just stop things being automatically tracked, they don't prevent you specifically tracking a file anyway.

Comment: This saved me from writing a lot of, probably very much malfunctioning, code.